# Setting minimum date for multiple date pickers based on the selection from a date picker

Tags: jquery, datetime, datepicker

Is it possible to set the minimum date attribute of multiple jQuery date pickers when either one has a date selected.

For instance; if I have 5 date pickers, the minimum date should (for each) be at least 1 day after the day of the previous one.

Comment: What date pickers are you talking about? Which plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have see events of the datepicker where you can show date  depending on previous date selected on datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this functionality by changing the options of the datepicker on the fly.

```
$('#date1').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() {
    // Figure out value for new minimum
    $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newMinimum);
});
```

Put something like that in `$(document).ready()` and whenever a new date is selected in `date1`, the picker for `date2` will be updated.

Something to watch for: a datepicker's minimum date won't prevent someone from typing in an invalid date.  You can prevent this by making the field readonly.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I already have them as readonly and will be performing server-side validation.